# React Map each Children and add css style to each children

Tags: reactjs

I need to style each children when render

My first Component is side bar

**Mainpage.js**

```
<Sidebar>
  <Mycomp>
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <p>three</p>
  </Mycomp>
  <Mycomp postion="bottom">
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <p>three</p>
  </Mycomp>
</Sidebar>
```

In my **Sidebar.js** I have map for each children like this

```
const test=Children.map((this.props.children, child) => (
  <div className="hello">
    {child}
  </div>
))
```

But the class hello div is only wrapped with `Mycomp` component

I need to wrap class hello `div` tag to each `p` inside **Sidebar.js**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want. But this how you would inject styles to each components of `Children`

```
const test = Children.map(this.props.children, Component=>(
    <Component className="hello" />
))
```

Comment: When i console i have output is 2 children ,I think side Bar component  only taking Mycomp as children

Comment: I think you need to change the Variable to CamelCase "Test" so react knows it is a Component in the render 

The "Component" represent each component item in the list

Answer (score 0):

```
const test = this.props.children.map(child => (
     <div className="hello">
         {child}
     </div>
))
```

Comment: Ok, can you tell me what is this "Children"? 
And can you console log "this.props.children" - to check how many item you have there. 
Let me know what value you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
const test=Children.map(this.props.children,child=>(
    {Children.map(child.props.children, child=> <div className="hello">{_child}</div>)}
))
```

try this!